# ES Search failing for italian analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

In my application, I support localization in search. I am using elastic search but I am having trouble using italian analyzer. Note that other analysers work correctly but only the italian analyzer raises the following error.

```
{
    "total": 25,
    "successful": 20,
    "failed": 5,
    "failures": [{
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "default_37",
        "node": "hhgqY2HtRWeAFZehZgVC5w",
        "reason": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Invalid format: \"test\""
        }
    }]
}
```

My query looks like this:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "mongo",
                    "fields": ["keywords", "tag", "*_it", "subject", "body"]
                }
            }],
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "term": {
                            "instanceid": "6"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "terms": {
                            "articlesectionid": [1]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "term": {
                            "status": 1
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "keywords": {},
            "tag": {},
            "*_it": {},
            "subject": {},
            "body": {}
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how my mapping looks like:

```
{
    "default_37": {
        "mappings": {
            "articles": {
                "properties": {
                    "articlesectionid": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "boost": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "contents_ar": {
                        "analyzer": "arabic",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_bg": {
                        "analyzer": "bulgarian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_bs": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_ca": {
                        "analyzer": "catalan",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_cs": {
                        "analyzer": "czech",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_da": {
                        "analyzer": "danish",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_de": {
                        "analyzer": "german",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_el": {
                        "analyzer": "greek",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_en-gb": {
                        "analyzer": "english",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_en-us": {
                        "analyzer": "english",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_es": {
                        "analyzer": "spanish",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_es-419": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_et": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_fi": {
                        "analyzer": "finnish",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_fil": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_fr": {
                        "analyzer": "french",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_he": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_hr": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_hu": {
                        "analyzer": "hungarian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_id": {
                        "analyzer": "indonesian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_is": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_it": {
                        "analyzer": "italian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_ja": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_ko": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_lt": {
                        "analyzer": "lithuanian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_lv": {
                        "analyzer": "latvian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_ms": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_nl": {
                        "analyzer": "dutch",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_no": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_pl": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_pt": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_pt-br": {
                        "analyzer": "brazilian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_ro": {
                        "analyzer": "romanian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_ru": {
                        "analyzer": "russian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_sk": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_sl": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_sr": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_sv": {
                        "analyzer": "swedish",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_th": {
                        "analyzer": "thai",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_tr": {
                        "analyzer": "turkish",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_uk": {
                        "analyzer": "english",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_vi": {
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_zh-cn": {
                        "analyzer": "cjk",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contents_zh-tw": {
                        "analyzer": "cjk",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "createdat": {
                        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "instanceid": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "keywords": {
                        "term_vector": "yes",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "object": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "objecthash": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "objectid": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "type": "short"
                    },
                    "tag": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_ar": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "arabic",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_bg": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "bulgarian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_bs": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_ca": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "catalan",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_cs": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "czech",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_da": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "danish",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_de": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "german",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_el": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "greek",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_en-gb": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "english",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_en-us": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "english",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_es": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "spanish",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_es-419": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_et": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_fi": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "finnish",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_fil": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_fr": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "french",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_he": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_hr": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_hu": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "hungarian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_id": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "indonesian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_is": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_it": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "italian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_ja": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_ko": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_lt": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "lithuanian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_lv": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "latvian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_ms": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_nl": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "dutch",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_no": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_pl": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_pt": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_pt-br": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "brazilian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_ro": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "romanian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_ru": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "russian",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_sk": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_sl": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_sr": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_sv": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "swedish",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_th": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "thai",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_tr": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "turkish",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_uk": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "english",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_vi": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_zh-cn": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "cjk",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "title_zh-tw": {
                        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                        "search_analyzer": "cjk",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "updatedat": {
                        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                        "type": "date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. Mappings looks correct. There should be no reason why should raise `Invalid format` error.

Answer (score 0):

is there a stack trace in your log files? If so, please provide it. Also does this happen as well, if you remove the highlighting part of your query? Also, can you create a minimal reproducible example, that only contains the italian analyzer and a sample document, that would allow others to reproduce the issue. Thanks!